# How to traverse List[IO] to execute everything and collect all errors?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

For example I have a list of IO with some errors.

```scala
def print(x: Int) = {
  if(x == 3 || x == 4) 
    IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("error " + x))
  else 
    IO(println(x))
}

List.range(1,6).map(print)
```

If I use traverse

```scala
List.range(1,6).map(print)
```

It prints only 1,2 and I can get one error "error 3"
I would like to print all numbers

```
1 
2
5
```

and get list of all errors

```
List("error 3", "error 4")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```scala
List.range(1, 6).traverse(print(_).attempt)
   .map(_.collect{case Left(x) => x})
```